# Loading a webform into iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my project I have created a menu list. When I click on a menu item it should load a given page into an iframe on same page.  However, it is loading as separate page, not into the iframe. Why is this?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
   function changeFrm(NewSrc){
       document.getElementById('middleiD').src = NewSrc;}
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" onClick='ChangeFrm("WebUserControl.ascx")'>Calendar</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a `return false;` in your `onclick` event which tells the original click to stop bubbling

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" onClick='ChangeFrm("WebUserControl.ascx"); return false;'>Calendar</asp:HyperLink>
```

well, to stop duping, add that to you function:

```
function changeFrm(NewSrc){
   document.getElementById('middleiD').src = NewSrc;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: is WebUserControl.ascx a valid url? should be .aspx? you've also no closing script tag